# Wamp Virtual Host Set Up

Tags: wamp, virtual-hosts

sorry for having a similar question to what has been posted all ready but the others aren't helping me. 
I'm trying to set up a virtual host on my windows 8 computer but I can't seem to get it to work no matter what tutorial or help section i follow, this is my setup so far.

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\2. Apps\Wamp\www"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Projects\testsite\Site"
    ServerName testingsite
    ServerAlias testingsite
    <directory "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Projects\testsite\Site">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts**

```
# Wamp Server Settings
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       testingsite
```

**httpd.conf**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

If i try to start wamp the icon goes orange.
If i run httpd.exe from command prompt i get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\2. Apps\Wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\bin>httpd.exe
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:
80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I read that another program might be blocking it or my firewall but i don't know how to fix it, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try taking `Listen 80` out of your vhosts.conf. Mine has `NameVirtualHost *:80` instead.

Comment: I thought i had tried with that and it didn't work but it has now fixed it... Thanks. I got the listen 80 from the apache help docs to

Comment: @SarahKemp one last one - do you know why i get a 403 forbidden page?

Comment: Nothing stands out in the configs you have shown. This topic has a few things you can try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204902/wamp-403-forbidden-message Make sure you remember to restart Apache whenever you make changes to your conf files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's input, there were two main problems

I installed wamp into a folder which was nested in a folder who's name had a space in so `c:/folder/folder with a space/wamp/` which i have since been told is bad practice, if anyone knows why please tell.

The were issues with the internet protocol, namely `ipv6`, so solve this you need to ensure wamp only uses `ipv4`, inside `httpd.conf` find `Listen 80` and change to `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`. Again i'm not sure what this does so if anyone knows please post below.

I hope this helps anyone else stuck.