# Local web development for multiple sites

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I use *WampServer* in order to test my sites locally. I'm reorganizing my development environment and I faced this issue:

I want to have multiple folders inside the root www folder of *WampServer*. Each subfolder represents one site.

My problem now is that every relative link that starts with `/` is not working, since it takes `localhost` as the root instead of `localhost/subfolder/`. For example:

- `<a href="/">...`
- `<img src="/images/...`

Also, every site has its own `.htaccess` file and inside I use `RewriteBase /`. Now, this line breaks all my `RewriteRules` since takes `/subfolder/` as part of the URL.

My only idea to solve this is by using [**virtual hosts**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717739/wamp-server-virtual-hosts-configuration) for every site, so instead of having `localhost/subfolder/`, I will have something like `subfolder.dev`.

Changing relative links or `.htaccess` files of all my existing sites is not an option. Virtual hosts seems to be what I need, but it requires modifying `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` every time I add a new site.

Is there any other way to configure my *WampServer* (Apache) to work in the way I need?

**Update:** I just finish to configure Virtual hosts for all my sites and everything works perfect. So, I leave the question open in case there exists an easier solution.

By the way, how does paid hostings deal with multiple domains under one customer account? Do they use Virtual hosts too?

Comment: You have picked the correct solution i.e. Virtual Hosts. There is no automated way to do this, but once you have done it for a few sites its just a copy/paste and change a few folder names and the ServerName and DocumentRoot and add a HOSTS definition. So its not a big deal

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your comment! at least now I know that I'm in the right direction :)

Comment: I believe hosting companies use something like Virtual Hosts but not necessarily exactly like you and I do it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly you seem reliable, have you deal with this: [Reuse PHP project in Eclipse / Aptana Studio 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344771/reuse-php-project-in-eclipse-aptana-studio-3)?