# Reuse PHP project in Eclipse / Aptana Studio 3

Tags: php, project, aptana, eclipse-pdt

I have a CMS project that I reuse in several sites.

Is it possible to add this project as Library for other PHP projects?

For development, I have the files of my CMS included in one site and not in the others. Then, from that only copy I upload the files through every site. I want to improve this.

I read [Configuring a Project's PHP Build Path](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/configuring_build_paths.htm) and [Configuring a Project's PHP Include Path](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/adding_elements_to_a_project_s_include_path.htm). However, I don't see how the project' files will be included in the site if I test it locally.

I use *WampServer* to test my sites, but all the files need to be in the site folder in order to run. So, how can I develop the CMS in one Project and avoid having the CMS files duplicate through all my sites?

I don't know if I was clear. Lets asume I have WordPress as a project and I'm developing multiple WordPress sites. How can I include the WordPress  project in the sites and test them locally?

Comment: [this is one of the options for instance](http://roots.io/using-composer-with-wordpress/). Composer is a great tool, but you could also just define a git repo with some submodules.

Comment: @Wrikken If I define a git submodule for the CMS in every site, is it possible to add different files in the CMS folder between sites? I mean, I have configuration files inside the CMS that differ across sites. Git submodules will allow me to have different files or I need to take those files to a root folder?