# Virtual Host configuration for Wamp

Tags: php, apache

I am writing one web application using php, But I don't know how to access my website directly from localhost.

I have configured VirtualHost in apache but still not working,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/top10"
    ServerName top10.com

    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/top10" >
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also add the same ServerName entry in **hosts** file

When I try to access I am getting following error

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at top10.com Port 80
```

I want to access my website as http://top10.com instead of http://localhost/top10.

Could you please help me for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [WAMP Server virtual hosts configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717739/wamp-server-virtual-hosts-configuration)

Comment: I did the same thing but still not able to access

Comment: Did you try adding the alias to the host file?

Comment: After you have done changes please restart WAMP server in order to make changes.

Comment: Host entry are as follow 
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1  top10.com
::1   top10.com

Comment: It is working now. Thanks

Comment: Great..if my comments were helpful up vote them

Answer (score 1):

Open hosts file ( AS Administrator ) in C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/ and add the following line ( Don't delete anything )

127.0.0.1 myWebsite.local

change myWebsite.local as per your name requirements

Comment: I did the same thing but still same issue