# APP_URL not refreshing after a change

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-9

I'm building a Laravel 9 app using Docker.

I'm just starting, so I merely updated the `APP_URL` variable in the `.env` (from "http://localhost" to "http://mydomain.local").

After this, I ran the following commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

and I restarted the Docker container of the app.

Yet, when I access `http://mydomain.local` in my browser, the app doesn't load. It still loads properly when I user `http://localhost` as originally configured.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your web server configured to respond to that domain (apache/nginx) ? And do your dns correctly resolve this domain ?

Comment: My web server? You mean Docker? Do I need to configure this in Docker separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you probably didnt edit the vhost..

Just changing the APP_URL in the .env file doesnt change how the browser resolves a domain name.

See this thread to learn how to edit a vhost file: [WAMP Server virtual hosts configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717739/wamp-server-virtual-hosts-configuration)