# 403 Forbidden on wamp server

Tags: apache

I setup my wamp server and can access phpMyAdmin directory on the local host.

I'm trying to access a file from my directory but it gives me error 403 Forbidden yet I've tried to change my `httpd.conf` to

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And I've also changed my `phpadmin.conf` to

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
      Allow from 127.0.0.1
      Allow from MACHINE_IP
```

And I still can't access some files on my server

Here is the exact message:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /php_sandbox/e-commerce/4-full-mvc-framework/views/login/index.php on
>   this server.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204902/wamp-403-forbidden-message

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-do-i-change-folder-and-file-permissions/465f2b42-63dd-4486-8dd1-c870290efeed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WAMP 403 Forbidden message on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204902/wamp-403-forbidden-message-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

In your phpadmin.conf these lines are your problem:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from MACHINE_IP
```

change this to

```
Allow from all
```

and it should work.

Comment: <Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from all
   Allow from MACHINE_IP
   
</Directory> still showing me the same error message