# How do i get rid of the 403-forbidden-error on WAMP host?

Tags: php, apache, xhtml, wamp

I am developing my first website and launched it on WAMP Server, i am running windows 10, it was working ok, till the OS had an update; now i am getting a 403 Forbidden message; how do i get rid of the 403-forbidden-error on WAMP host?

```
ServerAdmin admin@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName localhost:80
```

do I have to make any changes?

```
ServerRoot "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204902/wamp-403-forbidden-message-on-windows-7 check it

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit dangerous using a preview version of Windows as a development environment.

Check that the Windows update didnt revert the HOSTS file back to the default

```
C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Should contain at least :-

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1  localhost
```

Make sure they are not commented out with a `#` in column 1