# HttpURLConnection get 403 Error (localhost)? - Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using from `HttpURLConnection` to connect to a `localhost`, I connect my mobile with `USB tethering` to my `PC(windows 10)` and then I test my app don't get me result, get me `403`.Structure of my result is JSON:

```
{"0":2,"1":3,"2":4,"HELLO":2,"OK":"LOLO"}
```

Bellow is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CatalogClient client = new CatalogClient();
        client.execute("http://192.168.42.104/web/MySite/index.php");
      }
}
```

And my `AsyncTask` code is :

```
public class CatalogClient extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {
    String responseString;
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        JSONArray response = new JSONArray();

        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                responseString = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                Log.v("CatalogClient", responseString);
                response = new JSONArray(responseString);
            } else {
                Log.v("CatalogClient", "Response code:" + responseCode);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return response;
    }


    private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.i("LOG",line);
                response.append(line);
            }
            return response.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return "NULL";
    }
}
```

And I get IP from `cmd` :

[image]

NOTICE : I am using `UwAmp` and my `Apache port is 80`.

Comment: `localhost` ? What do you mean? The android device is its own local host. The pc is its own localhost. Every device is its own localhost.

Comment: 403 ? What does it mean? And where do you see one?

Comment: `Structure of my result is JSON:` ? But you said you had no result.

Comment: `And I get IP from cmd :`. Did you type any command?

Comment: I should get result from address ,Json.

Comment: I typed in cmd ,ipconfig.

Comment: i think it's related to apache setup, when using IP address of machine, not `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` something like enabling requests using machine IP , have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204902/wamp-403-forbidden-message-on-windows-7