# 403 Forbidden error in 32 bit WAMP

Tags: http-status-code-403, mantis

I installed WAMP 2.5, 32 bit on windows 2008 standard server. Everything looks fine on localhost but when tried from network I am having below error.

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at MYSERVER Port 80**

**access.log showing following error:**

```
my IP [11/Nov/2016:15:09:27 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 292
my IP [11/Nov/2016:15:09:27 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 303
my IP [11/Nov/2016:15:09:49 +0530] "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1" 403 302
my IP [11/Nov/2016:15:09:49 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 303
my IP [11/Nov/2016:15:09:54 +0530] "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1" 403 302
my IP [11/Nov/2016:15:09:54 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 303
```

Thanks in advance. It will helpful if someone give step by step changes for 32 bit version.

Comment: Can you post your error.log?

Comment: Parent: Created child process 5528
Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/mantisbt
client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico, referer: http://MyServer/mantisbt
client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/mantisbt
client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico, referer: http://MyServer/mantisbt
client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/mantisbt
client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico, referer: http://MyServer/mantisbt

Comment: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/mantisbt
client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico, referer: http://MyServer/mantisbt
client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/
client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico, referer: http://MyServer/
client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/
client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico, referer: http://XXX.XX.X.XX/

Comment: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
Child: All worker threads have exited.
Parent: Child process 5528 exited successfully.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:13:13
Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204902/wamp-403-forbidden-message-on-windows-7?rq=1   ---Bobs Yeruncle save my day. thanks