# Error code 403 when using WAMP for custom website

Tags: html, phpmyadmin, wampserver

When attempting to access a website i am attempting to host on my pc using WAMP i get the typical error code 403 forbidden. I have edited the apache config to allow all etc but still seem to get it, however i can see localhost and phpadmin from 127.0.0.1
Any other suggestions? i can attach my apache config or put it in a pastebin if needed

For reference im running Win10(64x) with WAMP Server 3.0.6 (64x)

I have followed multiple tutorials from youtube and stackoverflow but cannot seem to get it to work as most use commands given are from linux such as 'chmd' (i have used linux before therefor understand what this means but cant work out how to do the same thing via windows)

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204902/wamp-403-forbidden-message-on-windows-7

Comment: chmod is used to change permissions of files and folders, if the permission is not allowing you to read files it will give 403 Error, Try changing the permissions of file/folder from properties

Comment: @Purushotamrawat These config settings were the same as what i have here, still the same error

Comment: As to the permissions, full access is allowed by everyone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WAMP 403 Forbidden message on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204902/wamp-403-forbidden-message-on-windows-7)

Comment: did you add the wamp appache to the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Try making virtual host and give access to all local user. Make sure you give access to

```
file -------> httpd.conf

DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    #onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.0
</Directory>
```

Edit httpd-vhosts.conf As like:

```
file ------> httpd-vhosts.conf

# Virtual Hosts
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName smarthome
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/smarthome"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/smarthome/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```